# How to install Gradle with offline mode for Android studio using Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio

I'm looking a way to install `Gradle` for Android studio.
My Internet speed is very slow. It's below `8kbps` and When i start Android studio it takes too much time to download gradle(Almost 8 hrs). Please help! I've the latest version of Android studio and using `ubuntu 14.04 LTS`.

Really, Is that possible to install Gradle with `Offline mode` ? Please help

Answer (score 3):

You can download the Gradle file from http://www.gradle.org/downloads, then once you have that downloaded once you can just point Android Studio to the file within File > Settings > Gradle then check Local Gradle Distribution and browse for the location of where you have your Gradle download.

Answer (score 0):

Once you let the Gradle to be downloaded automatically for the first time while setting up your new projects ..

On laters projects you don't have to download them again ... and again :)
so left your PC for a night to download a Gradle and next morning you will have everything you needed.

Comment: Yes leave the pc for a night if you are from India, or leave for a couple of minutes otherwise. The latest version is 55 MB